# MQTT Library for Arduino using GSM

Tags: mqtt, arduino, gsm

I am developing a vehicle tracking device.I want to send data to server through MQTT from my sim808 GSM module.But I couldn't find any good library of MQTT for Arduino. There are so much resources for Wi-Fi module but I'm using a GSM module.

Comment: What research have you already done?

Comment: I have found a library in github but it didn't work properly.

Comment: Then you may do better posting on Stack Overflow with the code you've tried and somebody may be able to help you fix it

Comment: You will find this repository helpful: https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/tiny-gsm If you are stuck with 
 articular problem please post in details, as you question is kinda incomplete.

Comment: Hi Iqbal, can you post what exactly you tried? The relevant bits of code?

Comment: You need to find a GSM library that will mimic the Ethernet library Port, then you can use the standard MQTT

Answer (score 2):

There is a good library called `GSM_MQTT.h`for sending data through mqtt from GSM modules. [You can refer this site.](https://elementztechblog.wordpress.com/2016/07/18/arduino-mqtt-library-for-sim800-gsm-modem/)

Hope this helped.

Comment: Maybe its worth mentioning, that this lib is not developed any more and misses some important features like ssl/tls